# Multidimensional to simple array for frontend purposes

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array like below:

```
Array(
    [top_menu] => Array(
        [li] => Array(
            [a] => Array(
                [clr] => #FF00FF
            )

            [a:hover] => Array(
                [clr] => #FF6600
            )
        )
    )

    [wrap-zfcnt] => Array(
        [a] => Array(
            [clr] => #99CC00
        )

        [p] => Array(
            [ffam] => Comic Sans MS
            [clr] => #FF0000
            [fsz] => 9px
        )

        [a:hover] => Array(
            [clr] => #666699
            [txtd] => underline
        )
    )

    [sidebar-zfcnt] => Array(
        [bgi] => url(/res/uploads/webist/0/3/6815/res/18291/logo.png?1)
    )
)
```

I want to convert it to a single dimensional array like below:

```
[top_menu~li~a--clr] => #FF00FF
[top_menu~li~a:hover--clr] => #FF6600
[wrap-zfcnt~a--clr] => #99CC00
[wrap-zfcnt~p--fsz] => 9px
[wrap-zfcnt~p--ffam] => Comic Sans MS
[wrap-zfcnt~p--clr] => #FF0000
[wrap-zfcnt~a:hover--txtd] => underline
[wrap-zfcnt~a:hover--clr] => #666699
[sidebar-zfcnt--bgi] => url(/res/uploads/webist/0/3/6815/res/18291/logo.png?1)
```

Below is my function:

```
function m_dim_to_s_dim_css ($array, $el='') {
    $style = '';
    $style_block = '';

    $i=0;
    foreach ($array as $element => $styles ) {
        if ( is_array($styles) ) {
            if($el != '') {
                $element = $el.'~'.$element;
            }

            $cStyle = m_dim_to_s_dim_css($styles, $element);
            $style .= $cStyle;
        } else {
            if($i > 0) {

            }
            $style_block .= "--".$element;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if (!empty($style_block)) {
        $style .= $el.$style_block."=>".$styles."|||";
    }

    return $style;
}
```

this is what it is returning:

```
Array
(
    [top_menu~li~a--clr] => #FF00FF
    [top_menu~li~a:hover--clr] => #FF6600
    [wrap-zfcnt~a--clr] => #99CC00
    [wrap-zfcnt~p--ffam--clr--fsz] => 9px
    [wrap-zfcnt~a:hover--clr--txtd] => underline
    [sidebar-zfcnt--bgi] => url(/res/uploads/webist/0/3/6815/res/18291/logo.png?1)
    [] => 
)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: formatting on your post is quite bad. you're trying to use backticks for large code blocks and this doesn't work. large code blocks are identified using indents (best to highlight and use the code block button in the rich text editor)

Comment: The result looks like the expected result.. where is problem?

Comment: I added the example here: https://pastebin.com/AgAdBNKg. I'm not able to edit the question

Comment: @Kootsj What do you mean exactly?

Comment: @MehdiBounya problem is on these lines: 
[wrap-zfcnt~p--ffam--clr--fsz] => 9px
    [wrap-zfcnt~a:hover--clr--txtd] => underline
Notice, instead of --ffam, --clr and --fsz being in seperate lines, there are same key?

I have also pasted desired results over what I am getting...

Comment: I was actually asking @Kootsj about the link he posted. OP, I still don't see the problem and please never post long code in comments, I still can't see the difference between the expected result and the one you got from your function.

Comment: @David784 formatting has been fixed now. Please see if you can help!

Comment: @MehdiBounya line 4-6 in expected result is merged into one line no 4 in actual result

Comment: @MehdiBounya if you look at array -> wrap-zfcnt->p, it has 3 childs, they must be in three separate lines rather than one line like what I have ended up to...

Comment: @Mehdi Bounya I thought I would add the working script instead of a var_dump output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Her you have correct recursive loop:

```
<?php
$inArray = [
  'top_menu' => [
    'li' => [
      'a' => ['clr' => '#FF00FF'],
      'a:hover' => ['clr' => '#FF6600'],
    ],
  ],
  'wrap-zfcnt' => [
    'a' => ['clr' => '#99CC00'],
    'p' => [
      'ffam' => 'Comic Sans MS',
      'clr' => '#FF0000',
      'fsz' => '9px',
    ],
    'a:hover' => [
      'clr' => '#666699',
      'txtd' => 'underline',
    ],
  ],
  'sidebar-zfcnt' => ['bgi' => 'url(/res/uploads/webist/0/3/6815/res/18291/logo.png?1)',],
];

$reducedArray = [];

function walkStyleArray($toWalk, $keyPrefix = "") {
  global $reducedArray; //need for access outside function definied array
  if(is_array($toWalk)) {
    foreach($toWalk as $key => $value) {
      if(is_array($value)) {
        walkStyleArray($value, $keyPrefix . ($keyPrefix === "" ?"":"~") . $key);
      } else {
        $newKey = $keyPrefix  . ($keyPrefix === "" ?"":"--") . $key;
        $reducedArray[$newKey] = $value;
      }
    }
  }
}

walkStyleArray($inArray);

// print_r($inArray);
print_r($reducedArray);
```

And finally result:

```
Array
(
    [top_menu~li~a--clr] => #FF00FF
    [top_menu~li~a:hover--clr] => #FF6600
    [wrap-zfcnt~a--clr] => #99CC00
    [wrap-zfcnt~p--ffam] => Comic Sans MS
    [wrap-zfcnt~p--clr] => #FF0000
    [wrap-zfcnt~p--fsz] => 9px
    [wrap-zfcnt~a:hover--clr] => #666699
    [wrap-zfcnt~a:hover--txtd] => underline
    [sidebar-zfcnt--bgi] => url(/res/uploads/webist/0/3/6815/res/18291/logo.png?1)
)
```

---

**Edit 1 for the records:**

Walk array deeper and deeper until value meet (it is recurrency break case), and then create element of reducedArray, no counting needed either any other.

---

**Edit 2 walkStyleArray function without `global` statement**

```
$reducedArray = [];

function walkStyleArray(&$resultArray, $toWalk, $keyPrefix = "") {
  if(is_array($toWalk)) {
    foreach($toWalk as $key => $value) {
      if(is_array($value)) {
        walkStyleArray($resultArray, $value, $keyPrefix . ($keyPrefix === "" ?"":"~") . $key);
      } else {
        $newKey = $keyPrefix  . ($keyPrefix === "" ?"":"--") . $key;
        $resultArray[$newKey] = $value;
      }
    }
  }
}

walkStyleArray($reducedArray, $inArray);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works best. For some reason, I am getting 1 at the start of each key. Wonder why?

Comment: I have updated the code. Thanks heaps. I will mark it as a correct answer! Cheers

Comment: ?: operator in root level (when $keyPrefix === '') can does 1 at start the key value (not always, but) - for sure I correct is to `$keyPrefix == "" ? "":"~"` instead of 'short form' `$keyPrefix == "" ? :"~"` and the same with `--` separator

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is called `array_reduce`.

You've got an array like `$a = array(array(1,2,3), array(4,5), array(6,7,8,9))`

When you `print_r` that array it will give you such a multidimensional array structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 9
        )
)
```

and you want to merge it to one single array to look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
)
```

You simply have to make a new array

`$a` is your old, multi-dimensional array.
`$result` is your new, one-dimensional array.

```
$result = array_reduce($a, 'array_merge', array());
```

Hope I was able to help you with your problem.

Comment: That might solve somebody else's problem but not this particular problem I am afraid. Let me know if you can address that. Thanks